# Recyclerview data is changed without specify it

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-diffutils

I'm performing some operations in my model list to be passed after to recycler adapter and update the adapter list. For some unexpected reason the adapter list has been updated before i pass the new list. I'm using DiffUtil to calculate the difference between an oldList and newList.

```kotlin
internal fun CheckoutDetailsActivity.updateLineItemWithPartialPayment(lineItemModelToUpdate: LineItemModel){

    GlobalScope.launch {
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            calculateTodayPayments(lineItemModelToUpdate)
        }
    }
}

internal suspend fun  CheckoutDetailsActivity.calculateTodayPayments(lineItemModelToUpdate: LineItemModel){
    var todayPayments: BigDecimal = BigDecimal.ZERO
    val lineItems: ArrayList<LineItemModel> = ArrayList(viewModel.ticket?.lineItems)

    withContext(Dispatchers.Default){
        lineItems.forEachIndexed loop@{ index, lineItemModel ->
            if(lineItemModel.id == lineItemModelToUpdate.id){
                lineItems[index] = lineItemModelToUpdate
                todayPayments += lineItemModelToUpdate.partialPaymentAmount?: BigDecimal.ZERO
                return@loop
            }
            lineItemModel.inPartialPayment = true
            todayPayments += lineItemModel.partialPaymentAmount?: BigDecimal.ZERO
        }
    }

    viewModel.todayPayments = todayPayments

    updateRecyclerAdapter(lineItems)
    showTodayPaymentContainer()
}

internal fun CheckoutDetailsActivity.updateRecyclerAdapter(lineItems: ArrayList<LineItemModel>){
    viewModel.lineItemsWithPartialPayment.clear()
    viewModel.lineItemsWithPartialPayment.addAll(lineItems)
viewModel.recyclerViewAdapter?.submitList(viewModel.sortLineItems(ArrayList(lineItems)))
    viewModel.ticket?.lineItems = lineItems
}
```

this is my **submitList()** function in the adapter:

```kotlin
 fun submitList(lineItemList: List<LineItemModel>){
        val oldLineItemList = lineItems
        val diffResult: DiffUtil.DiffResult = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(
            LineItemDiffCallback(
                oldLineItemList,
                lineItemList
            )
        )
        this.lineItems.clear()
        this.lineItems.addAll(lineItemList)
        diffResult.dispatchUpdatesTo(this)
    }

    class LineItemDiffCallback(
        var oldLineItemList: List<LineItemModel>,
        var newLineItemList: List<LineItemModel>
    ): DiffUtil.Callback(){
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int): Boolean {
            return oldLineItemList[oldItemPosition].id == newLineItemList[newItemPosition].id
        }

        override fun getOldListSize(): Int {
           return oldLineItemList.size
        }

        override fun getNewListSize(): Int {
           return newLineItemList.size
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int): Boolean {
            return oldLineItemList[oldItemPosition] == newLineItemList[newItemPosition]
        }

    }
```

In the last method i'm updating the adapter list with **submitList()**, when i check the adapter list in **viewModel.todayPayments = todayPayments** line it has been already updated with the previous operation "forEachIndexed()", for that reason DiffUtil doesn't works correctly, because it can't find difference between **oldList** and **newList**.

Answer (score 0):

updateLineItemWithPartialPayment calls calculateTodayPayments that calls updateRecyclerAdapter that calls updateLineItemWithPartialPayment that calls calculateTodayPayments that calls updateRecyclerAdapter [...] **you get the point...**

Why are using extension functions? Aren't you calling them from the activity itself?

Another thing... is this `submitList` function yours or are you using a PagedListAdapter?

Comment: Ohh, sorry for that, was an error when i created the question but now is updated.